# List.ContainsAny within same column PowerQuery

Tags: list, datetime, compare, powerquery

I have a column containing lists of DateTimes

| Column F |
| --- |
| **List** |
| **List** |
| **List** |

I want to be able to identify:

For each list in column F,
if any content of current list is found on any other list
Flag that current list

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let Source = <whatever>,
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each List.Transform([Column1], each Number.From(_))),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1", each List.Combine(List.RemoveRange(#"Added Custom1"[Custom],[Index],1))),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Dupe", each List.ContainsAny([Custom.1],[Custom])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Custom", "Custom.1"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but when the date time value only occur once, it still outputs as True even though there are no other occurrences. Is there a way to set same occurrences to true.

Comment: That is not correct. If none of the items are on any other list (each is unique) then it shows as false. If some or all of the items are on another list, it shows true.  If you want to do something else, then provide proper sample data and desired output, like David asked.